# Telethon: Same entity type for a group and channel in telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I have a bunch of handles(@xyz) and I am trying to find if that handle belongs to a user, a group or a channel. To check it, I am trying with the below code:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types import Channel, Chat, User

async def check_handle(client,handle):
    username = handle
    try:
        entity = await client.get_entity(username)
        if entity:
            if isinstance(entity, User):  # Check if it's a User (private chat)
                print(f"{username} is a private chat.")
            elif isinstance(entity, Channel):  # Check if it's a Channel
                print(f"{username} is a channel.")
            elif isinstance(entity, Chat):  # Check if it's a Chat (group)
                print(f"{username} is a group.")
            else:
                print(f"Unable to determine the type of {username}.")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

    

........
........

await check_handle(client,'@aim4pg') # Call to the function.
```

The above code returns - "@aim4pg is a channel.", but I can clearly see on searching telegram that the mentioned handle is a group with X numbers of `members` in it.

I kind of know why it is happening - Both channel as well as group return Channel entity(I tried to experiment with one channel and one group). And if it is a user, it returns `User` entity.

Help needed: How to determine if it is a group or channel or user in Telethon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only three chat types in Telegram:

- User (can have .bot flag set)
- Channel (can have only one of the .megagroup or .broadcast flags set)
- Chat (small groups, they can have no username)

There can't be any other thing returned by get_entity.

The usual non-small groups are called "megagroup" in the api, they're also Channel in type and have similar behavior. channel is called broadcast.

to differentiate them:

```py
if isinstance(entity, Channel)
    if entity.megagroup: # (aka, if not entity.broadcast
        # it's a supergroup
    else:
        # it's a broadcast channel
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am still bit confused with the classification. Let me know if I am going wrong. If the entity returns Channel, it can either be a group or a channel, which is decided by another property called `megagroup`. If `entity.megagroup = True`, clearly it is a group, otherwise it is a Channel. And, if entity type is Chat, it is also a group, but a small group. So, if I can conclude.

If entity = ,



User --> ignore
Channel -> If it is a entity.megagroup, then group else channel
Chat -> Is a group.

Let me know if it's correct interpretation.

Comment: that's correct, also note that "small groups" aka chat, can't be public. they can't have usernames. it's the initial state when a group is created before its upgraded to a supergroup. it's to be ignored for your case of username usage.  so all you need is Channel objects, if .megagroup, it's "group" the majority of groups, else if `.broadcast` or `not .megagroup` it's just a channel, the ones you can't talk in but only subscribe.

Comment: Thanks I think it is all I need to move forward right now.

Answer (score 0):

Megagroups are `Channel`s with `megagroup` set to `True`: https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/channel.html